# Does zend framework have html parser like simple html dom?

Tags: php, zend-framework, parsing, html-parsing

Does zend framework have html parser like simple html dom?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called: [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.query.html)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use simple html dom?

Comment: To avoid having to add another library to the project? I'd say it's a valid desire. Although simplehtmldom is hard to beat.

Comment: @Gordon: Because it can't deal with faulty HTML code, which is what sets simple html dom and Zend_DOM apart.

Comment: @Gordon Did not know that, so yeah, native DOM could be used. But why do those other DOMs even exist then? :p

Comment: @Gordon Without offence, I'm more inclined to think the OP just thought multiple libraries (in this case Zend + SimpleHtmlDom) cannot be combined.

Comment: @Gordon The offence, had there been any, would've been to the OP, not you ;)

Comment: @Gordon: What clutter? They're hidden by default anyway. Removing them will make things look more confusing.